# Using punctuation correctly

Tags: punctuation

In the sentence:

> Are you going in or out, I replied,

Where should I place the punctuation?

Answer (score 1):

> "Are you going in or out?" I replied.

Punctuation before the last quote.
If you're describing the speech itself or describing the action involved in the speech, there should be a comma.

NOTE: Questions should always have a question mark. Question marks are always inside the quotes.

> "You cannot leave this place," I implored.
>
> "You are one naughty minx," I uttered alluringly.
>
> "Take this charm," *h*e said offering me the talisman. "It'll help you on your journey."
>
> "Take this charm!" He shouted shoving the talisman in my face. "Take it!"

Comment: "Take this charm," **He** said offering me the talisman. "It'll help you on your journey." -- This is just plain wrong, I think, unless that "he" deserves the capitalization. And because of this, I have to say that this answer is misleading.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Good catch. Yes, that is a mistake. Should be lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

I think you would do best to rephrase it:

I replied, "Are you going in or leaving"?

But if you wanted to stick with the form you currently have it in you could do something like this:

"Are you going in or out?"

Going with this option may be more ambiguous as to who is talking, but it really depends on the context.

[Possible Reference](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/punctuating-questions)